# Using data triggers with a GridSplitter

Tags: xaml

I am trying to create a `GridSplitter` which is mostly opaque, and then on mouseover, animates to become fully visible.  Here's what I've tried:

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="SplitterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
  <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

`GridSplitter`:

```
<GridSplitter 
    ResizeDirection="Columns"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Background="Red"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Width="4"
    Style="{StaticResource SplitterStyle}" />
```

I checked MSDN, and GridSplitter has all of the properties that I'm using, so it seems like it should be fine, but maybe I'm overlooking something obvious?

EDIT:

Is it possible to put a GridSplitter into another element?  I changed my style to:

```
<Style x:Key="SplitterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
             </Trigger.EnterActions>
             <Trigger.ExitActions>
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                     <Storyboard>
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                     </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
             </Trigger.ExitActions>
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Then, I put the GridSplitter into a Border and applied the style to the border, instead:

```
<Border
    Style="{StaticResource SplitterStyle}"
    Background="{StaticResource WindowBorderBrush}"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Width="4"
    Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <GridSplitter ResizeDirection="Columns" Background="Red" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext"/>
</Border>
```

The border works great!  But now, the GridSplitter is nowhere to be found (the red background is no shown, the cursor doesn't change when I hover over the border, and there's nothing to drag to resize anything).  Why is this?

EDIT:

OK, I found out that I have to specify a width for the `GridSplitter`.  Also, I changed the background for the `GridSplitter` to transparent, because I was never planning on using red.  Now, it displays and looks great, but it still doesn't actually resize anything :P  How do I get it to actually be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up with, which worked:

```
<Style x:Key="SplitterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and

```
<GridSplitter
    Background="{StaticResource WindowBorderBrush}"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Width="4"
    Grid.Column="0"
    ResizeDirection="Columns" 
    Style="{StaticResource SplitterStyle}" />
```

I thought I tried exactly that at least once before even posting the first time, but I guess not.  Anyway, it works great now.